# How to remove some characters from the following response using sed?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a response from a curl request which looks like this :

```
[
"string1",
"string2",
"string3"
]
```

I want to remove the characters [ " , ] from the response using sed. How to do that. I tried some combinations, but none worked. My formatted response should look like this :

`string1 string 2 string3`

Comment: Is this a JSON array? Would it not be better to use a [JSON parser](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to handle it? Also, WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED?  Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a proper `JSON` parser like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for parsing `cURL` output. If you can install it, the processing is ever so simple,

```
<your-curl-response> | jq -r '.[]'
```

is all you need, where the `-r` flag on the filter produces a raw output without the double-quotes.

Use the `mapfile` command ( from `bash 4.0` onwards) to store it in array

```
mapfile -t jsonarray < <(<your-curl-command> | jq -r '.[]')
```

Then you can access elements as,

```
printf "%s\n" "${jsonarray[0]}"
```

Comment: how to access each element now like an array element. Now I have the response like :

string1

string2

string3
.
.
.
.
stringN

Now I want to access each string . How to do that ?

Comment: yes, my response is now

string1 
string2
string3
.
.
.
stringN

each string in a new line

Comment: basically my curl request sends me list of objects which i want to delete 1 by 1 using their name. @Inian

Comment: @sauravmajumder: can you see my update. Can you let me know you curl command and jq together, I will update the answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Using awk for cleaning:

```
$ arr=($(awk -v ORS=\  'gsub(/[\[\]\",]/,"")||1' file))
$ echo ${arr[*]}
string1 string2 string3
```

Explained:

- `awk -v ORS=\  '` use awk, set output record separator to space (instead of newline)
- `gsub(/[\[\]\",]/,"")` remove unwanted characters
- `||1` *or one* quarantees printing even when no substitutions are made
- `' file` filename

Solution expects `cURL` output to be in a file (named `file` above).

Comment: Really appreciate the prowess in `Awk` once again, but for some reason, `JSON` parsing in linux without `jq` doesn't rhyme well :)

Comment: It might not be JSON... (... who am I kidding...)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/\[|\]|"|,/,"",$0)}1' input | xargs
string1 string2 string3
```

or

```
curl command |awk '{gsub(/\[|\]|"|,/,"",$0)}1'| xargs
```

Here, awk is doing all the search and replacement tasks like replacement of `[ ] , "` . Once it it done `xargs` will bring multi-line output of `awk` into one line.

Comment: can you please tell me how to store this in an array ? 
i.e ,

array=(curl command |awk '{gsub(/\[|\]|"|,/,"",$0)}1'| xargs)

Comment: check Inian's answer please.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tr` for this:

```
echo $(tr -d '[\[\]",]' < your_file)
# output: string1 string2 string3
```

or

```
echo $(tr -d '[\[\]",]' < <(your curl command))
```